# How Vue is meant to be used in context of number of pages?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So, with default Vue CLI, I get Vue which loads from `index.html` page.
And everything else, I do in `App.vue` to work with Vue and dynamic contents on that page.

But what if I want to drastically change layout of page ?
Like, I don't know how I'm supposed to clean whole page, and start fresh ?
Then should I use another html page, which is somehow called from `index.html`, but then Vue won't work in that page, right ?

Not sure how this works.

Can I use something other than index.html to be default file on which Vue will look where to load (there is selector `mount('#app');`, but that selector only looks in `index.html` or I'm doing something wrong ? )

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you need to read up on [Single Page Applications](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/ways-of-using-vue.html#embedded-web-components:%7E:text=This%20type%20of%20application%20is,Client%2Dside%20router) that Vue helps you create.

To drastically change the layout of the page, is equivalent to jumping on a new page. Instead of rendering a new html page Vue helps you to clear the whole page and mount another component while also maintaining the history state for the browser. You can achieve this using [routing](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/routing.html#client-side-vs-server-side-routing).

What you are looking for is the official package that handles routing in a VueJS application; [Vue-Router](https://router.vuejs.org/).